# Can not launch Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I installed Spark 2.4 on Mac.

When I am trying to launch from command line, using **spark**, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Applications/anaconda3/bin/spark", line 2, in <module>
 from spark import spark_admin
File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spark/spark_admin.py", line 49
 os.chmod(join(proj_dir,'etc','cgiserver.py'),0755)
                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

When launching using **pyspark**, I get a Jupyter window open.

My .bash_profile is:

```
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/
export PATH="$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH"
export PYTHONPATH="$SPARK_HOME/python:$PYTHONPATH"
...
HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop-2.9.2/
```

What is this error and how can that be fixed?

Comment: How did you install Spark? This doesn't look like any standard installation.

Answer (score 0):

You have not set the configurations in `~/.bashrc` file correctly, you missed enclosing paths in single quotes. Also, if you want stand alone setup of `Spark`, you need not set `HADOOP_HOME`.

Refer to these lines below from my setup:

```
export SPARK_HOME='/home/kr_user/tools/spark/'
export PATH=${SPARK_HOME}/bin:$PATH
```

Add these lines in `~/.bashrc` file and refresh the environment using command:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

This would work for you.